# NuGet - what am I missing?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I've just started trying to use NuGet to version libraries (we have MANY shared libraries that are currently referenced directly by solutions) and having numerous problems.

So I generated a NuGet package (nuget spec -> edit file -> nuget pack) and put several versions of the same .dll (packaged) in a shared folder on the network.

Last week I opened one of my solutions and deleted one of the shared .csproj files (that converts to a .dll) from a solution and then added the NuGet package to the other .csproj files that needed it and everything seemed to work fine. But I never checked in the changes and undid them. Now I'm trying to do the same thing over again and when I right-click the project and choose Manage NuGet Packages it already shows the NuGet package as installed (a green check-mark next to the name). And I've deleted all of the source and re-gotten it fresh out of TFS, so why does it show that the project already has the package? I've tried clearing my NuGet cache as well (both from the UI and nuget locals all -clear from the commandline). And yet if I try to delete that shared library (.csproj) the solution no longer compiles.

I also can't find where to set the acceptable versions like let's say that I'm ok using versions 1.0 - 2.2

Apparently I'm using NuGet 2.12.0.817 (at least that's what it says in Help->About) with Visual Studio 2013.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong here? I'm quickly becoming overwhelmed by all of the NuGet documentation and realizing that I may be in over my head!

Comment: Have you tried (uninstalling and reinstalling)||Upgrading your nuget package(s) for the solution?

Comment: You mean the generated packages? Yes - I've moved them out of the shared directory and generated new ones, but I really need to uninstall them from the solution/.csproj files. I've completely deleted the entire source folder and re-gotten it from source control and yet the package still shows as installed. How do I uninstall them? That's the issue here really - I don't know how to uninstall them for the solution/.csproj files.

Comment: RightClick Solution>ManageNugetPackage>SelectInstalledPackage>SelectProjects>Uninstall. Does this work?

Comment: Yes - that works. Thanks. I also found the .packages file in the referenced project in a different folder from my current solution, so when I re-got my code that file wasn't overwritten and the package still appeared there.

Comment: Awesome! So is the problem solved now?Cause if yes, you should summarize what you did and self answer it now. I'm new to SE but I think this is what people do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the .packages file in the referenced project in a different folder from my current solution, so when I re-got my code that file wasn't overwritten and the package still appeared there. I'm still having numerous other problems, but I'll post on that separately.